# Flutter & Geocoder & Geolocator : How do I get the country name in English?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, locale

I have been trying to get the phone location. And for reason, the geocoder gets the country name in Korean. The phone main language is in English anyway. But why do I get it in Korean tho?

```
_getCurrentLocation() async {
      Position position =
          await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      final coordinates =
          new Coordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);

      final addresses =
          await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
      var first = addresses.first;
      print(first.adminArea);
      print(first.countryName);
    }
```

Console

```
I/flutter ( 7221): We have Latitude: 37.4219983, Longitude: -122.084
I/flutter ( 7221): Latitude : 37.4219983 & Longtitude : -122.084
I/flutter ( 7221): California
I/flutter ( 7221): 미국
```

Please have a look and help me in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 String _address = ""; // create this variable

void _getPlace() async {
 List<Placemark> newPlace = await 
_geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(_position.latitude, _position.longitude);

// this is all you need
 Placemark placeMark  = newPlace[0]; 
 String name = placeMark.name;
 String subLocality = placeMark.subLocality;
 String locality = placeMark.locality;
 String administrativeArea = placeMark.administrativeArea;
 String postalCode = placeMark.postalCode;
 String country = placeMark.country;
 String address = "${name}, ${subLocality}, ${locality}, ${administrativeArea} 
 ${postalCode}, ${country}";

 print(address);

  setState(() {
  _address = address; // update _address
   });
  }
```

Comment: i didnt find placemarkFromCoordinates , geolocator: ^8.2.1

Comment: ok...but how does it solve the problem? If the phones lang is not eng then the country name will be in another language like korean, or whatever the user set as default on their phones

Answer (score 1):

Change your phone language. Or using a "first.countryCode".